# Exported Swift Framework using SwiftyJSON is facing: Terminating app due to uncaught exception

Tags: objective-c, swift, frameworks, swifty-json

I am creating Swift Framework to parse some JSON data to be used in Objective C project and facing this error :

here is my framework code in Swift  in addtion to SwiftyJson library

```
import Foundation

@objc public class parse : NSObject {
  public override init() {
  }

  var Api = "XXXXXXX"

  @objc public func parseJSON(){
    print("flag")

    let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: Api)!
    let urlRequest: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: requestURL as URL)
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
      if data != nil {
        do {
          let readableJSON =  try JSON(data: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
          let Name = readableJSON["data"]["buttonText"].stringValue as String!
          let buttonTextColor = readableJSON["data"]["buttonTextColorCode"].stringValue as String!
          let buttonBackgroundColorCode = readableJSON["data"]["buttonBackgroundColorCode"].stringValue as String!
          let visibility = readableJSON["data"]["visibility"].boolValue
          let indexURL = readableJSON["data"]["indexURL"].stringValue as String!
          let authURL = readableJSON["data"]["authURL"].stringValue as String!
          let module = readableJSON["data"]["module"].stringValue as String!
          let alignment = readableJSON["data"]["alignment"].stringValue as String!

          print("\(Name!) \n \(buttonTextColor!) \n \(buttonBackgroundColorCode!) \n  \(indexURL!) \n \(alignment!)")

          print("done")
          print("Color value:\(buttonBackgroundColorCode!)")
        } catch {
          print(error)
        } 
      }  
    }

    task.resume()
  } 
}
```

and here is my project in Objective C :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@import JSONFrameWork;
#import <JSONFrameWork/JSONFrameWork-Swift.h>
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  [[parse alloc]init];
  [[parse alloc]parseJSON];
}

@end
```

and when I run the code getting the error below, I am suspecting SwiftyJSON is not functioning well in ObjetiveC

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initWithString:relativeToURL:]: nil string parameter'
*** First throw call stack:
(......) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Note: This framework works fine in Swift project and here is JSON response from API:

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "buttonText":"\u067e\u06cc\u0634 \u0628\u06cc\u0646\u06cc \u06a9\u0646!",
      "buttonTextColorCode":"#000000",
      "buttonBackgroundColorCode":"#7ca2d246",
      "visibility":true,
      "indexURL":"XXXXXX",
      "authURL":"XXXXX",
      "module":"MATCH_PREDICTION",
      "alignment":"RIGHT_TOP",
      "marginTop":"10",
      "marginLeft":"10",
      "marginRight":"10",
      "marginBottom":"10",
      "allowChannels":[  
         "22",
         "52",
         "10"
      ]
   },
   "success":true
}
```

Comment: post the json.......

Comment: you mean the json response ?

Comment: yes......................

Comment: question updated .........

Comment: sure that `Api` is valid ??

Comment: sure the same framework is working in swift project

Comment: `[[parse alloc]init]; [[parse alloc]parseJSON];` That's really strange. I'd do: `parse *p = [[parse alloc] init]; [parse parseJSON];`. But `parse` should be named `Parse` with an uppercase.

Comment: thanks now it works fine